# When to use dfn and dt together?

Tags: html

According to [HTML5Doctor's article on the dl element](http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/): "`<dl>` can be used to mark-up a glossary of terms, although you must remember to use `<dfn>` to indicate that the word is defined [in the same document]." Note: the bracketed language is my own. The article gives this markup to explain:

```
<dl>
  <dt><dfn>RSS</dfn></dt>
  <dd>An XML format for aggregating information from websites whose
    content is frequently updated.</dd>
</dl>
```

Note that the term "RSS" is enclosed in both `dt` and `dfn` tags.

My question is this: why must we remember to use `dfn`? That isn't explained convincingly. I'm looking for definitive explanation of `dfn` usage as well as some concrete examples.

Note: I looked at [The dfn tag documentation by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dfn.html) but that didn't answer my question.

#### Additional Background and References

Interestingly (or not), according to the [HTML5Doctor article](http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/) the `dl` element was renamed to 'description list' in HTML5. Formerly it the 'definition list'. From the [W3C Working Draft on the Description List](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dl.html#dl):

> The dl element represents a description list, which consists of zero or more term-description (name-value) groupings; each grouping associates one or more terms/names (the contents of dt elements) with one or more descriptions/values (the contents of dd elements).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Interestingly (or not), according to the [HTML5Doctor article](http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/) the `dl` element was renamed to 'description list' in HTML5.

That sums it up; now that `dl` is no longer exclusively applicable to *definition* lists, but to any kind of lists which contain terms and their corresponding *descriptions*, the `dfn` tag is recommended use to indicate that **the content of the `dt` is in fact a *definition* term**; that is, a term whose description is in fact its definition (something once necessarily true in previous specifications but no longer in HTML5).

Confusing, I know, but that's the basic idea: use `dfn` in a `dt` if the content of the `dt` is something that's being defined by its `dd`.

Comment: It's not mandated by the way; if you think it's unnecessary to contain a `dfn` in a `dt` for all your definitions then you don't have to. It's an issue of semantics, not one of markup validity.

Comment: Thanks for eloquently pointing out what was right in front my face! (Now I'm looking for the <facepalm> tag!)

Comment: @BoltClock "It's an issue of semantics, not one of markup validity." True, but that doesn't make it unimportant. The whole point of writing (html) documents is to serve humans, that is to make it readable and searchable for them. Search engines and screen readers will know these tags and serve people accordingly. I'd rather write semantically correct markup (to serve people) than syntactically correct (to serve machines). E.g. I couldn't care less about strict xhtml. MHO.

Answer (score 2):

As I just learned, a good time to use `dt` without `dfn` is for metadata. Here is an example that was right under my nose in the same [definition list writeup](http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/):

> `<dl>` is also appropriate for marking up content metadata, such as information about our article on how to use HTML5 in your client work right now."

Here is the markup:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Authors:</dt>
  <dd>Remy Sharp</dd>
  <dd>Rich Clark</dd>
  <dt>Editor:</dt>
  <dd>Brandan Lennox</dd>
  <dt>Category:</dt>
  <dd>Comment</dd>
</dl>
```

(One small criticism of this example: the ":" is marked up as being part of the term, but really, it is used as a delimiter.)

Comment: Well, you *could* use `dt::after` to insert the ":" delimiters.

Comment: True... I thought about that. But how precise do we really need to get? Does anyone care? I'm not sure if I really do after all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Nobody covered this, from the original blog to this post. The reason is this:

```
<dl>
  <dt><dfn>RSS</dfn> flibbit </dt>
  <dd>An XML format for ...</dd>
</dl>
```

You can add non-definition-target verbiage to the `<dt>`, so CSS marks it up as defined-term side, not definiton-data side.

That couples with the rule the `<dfn>` must appear once per `<dl>` (else someone scanning for it could be confused).